# I can't get openimage denoise to work on linux

Tags: node-editor, linux, denoise

I saw this questions asked already, but the way they explained the solution made no sense.

I only got linux two days ago, can someone please tell me step by step how to get it working.[image: This is the error]

Comment: Where did you get the build you are using? Is it self compiled? It does not appear to have openimage denoise enabled from the image you have posted. Not all of blenders configuration options are mandatory for building.

Comment: How did you install blender? Can you point to the link for the other question?